# Flutter; TextField RegExp diffrent proporties for diffrent places in the text

Tags: flutter, text, textfield

I have a TextField that has these proporties;

```
inputFormatters: [WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp("[0-9]")),],
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                          maxLength: 2,
                          maxLengthEnforced: false,
```

> this is so it only types with numbers, and not more than 2.

I want the first number to be between 0-5, and the last to be 0-9, this is because it is used for a minute count, so no more than 59.

How can I change to from a max of 99 to a max of 59 when the outcome is a String, so it's also not possible to check when depositiong the value back.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with the validator property of a text field , this is an example:

```
TextFormField(
  // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
  validator: (value) {
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Please enter some text';
    }
    return null;
  },
);
```

Comment: But I want to check weather the value of a String is higher or lower than 59. But I can also use this so the user fills out everything ( witch was another problem i had ;D )

Comment: you have the value variable that is in the example, then parse it to int and then check that is lower or higer than 59